# Storing the (array data)session in core data iOS

Tags: ios, objective-c, core-data

In my application I have seven category button on `firstController` which open `secondController`(tableView) having arrays of question. This question are in tableView which having Yes, NO buttons option for check/uncheck marks. Selecting Yes-No option will change the colour of `tableView` row. After answering the question the user can generate audit report(1st session). This report is usually PDF file. I am printing all the checked question on the PDF page and saving.

I have used `NSUserDefault` for saving all the array of checked question and NSDocumentDirectory for saving PDF file. In the current scenario, the User has to reset all the thing before he want to work for the second audit report(second session).

Now customer want the flexibility to save 1st incomplete audit report in database and would like to go for completing second audit report. Hence he can complete 1st audit report later and so on...

I have never used `Core Data` before, hence will the core data help me in above scenario. How can I apply logic here from scratch. Can some one give me the better idea. thanks in advance.

**Edited with Explanation**

I have 400 question array list taken in `tableView` with check/uncheck button. But for audit, user can checked question by his wish. say 100 question he checked so that he would save 100 question and print as a PDF pages.
User would like to have chance to save all incomplete session of checked-unchecked question to access it later to convert this as a PDF file.

Which method will be better?

Comment: Have you looked here? http://www.raywenderlich.com/934/core-data-tutorial-for-ios-getting-started

Comment: Why core data? Why not plist files on disk?

Comment: Just added more detail to the question. Can you plz check.

Answer (score 0):

If you just have an array or booleans or identifiers for your selected rows, don't use Core Data. Instead, just save the array to disk using `writeToFile:atomically:` and read it back in when required using `initWithContentsOfFile:`. You only want to consider Core Data if you want to store more information.

---

You can also have an array of dictionaries. Store the whole thing, not just the edited values (to make indexing easy). Colours are interesting. You could encode them into strings as comma separated rgb values or use an archived to convert them into data. You can't directly put the colours into a plist. You could put the colours into core data as transformable.

Comment: Just added more detail to the question. Can you plz check

Comment: Yeh, still just an array of identifiers / bools so save to a (plist) file.

Comment: Should I just saved check/Uncheck question array or entire Array in plist? And where should I save colour changed of an tableView.index after pressing the buttons? Can you elaborate the logic. Thanks:)